# Sort NSArray with custom objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, sorting, nssortdescriptor

In my Xcode project I have the following classes:

**Address**

```
@interface LDAddress : NSObject{
    NSString *street;
    NSString *zip;
    NSString *city;
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *street;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *zip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *city;
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) float latitude;
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) float longitude;

@end
```

**Location**

```
@interface LDLocation : NSObject{
    int locationId;
    NSString *name;
    LDAddress *address;
}
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) int locationId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) LDAddress *address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

In an subclass of UITableViewController, there is a NSArray containing a lot of unsorted objects of LDLocations. Now, I want to sort the NSArray's objects ascending based on the property *city* of a LDAddress.

How can I sort the array using NSSortDescriptor?
I tried the following, but the app dumps when sorting the array.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Address.city" ascending:YES];
[_locations sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: have you tried just @"city" as the key?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try making the first key lowercase.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"address.city" ascending:YES];
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also sort an array with blocks:

```
    NSArray *sortedLocations = [_locations sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(LDAddress *a1, LDAddress *a2) {
        return [a1.city compare:a2.city];
    }];
```

Comment: I tried your coding and it worked, but I like sorting an array with NSSortDescriptor more.

Answer (score 3):

This will allow to sort with multiple types. Like we need to sort the Movie based on time and if the time is equal then need to sort by name.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [childrenArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSNumber *first = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[(Movie*)a timeInMillis]];
        NSNumber *second = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[(Movie*)b timeInMillis]];
        NSComparisonResult result =  [first compare:second];
        if(result == NSOrderedSame){
            result = [((NSString*)[(Movie*)a name] ) compare:((NSString*)[(Movie*)b name])];
        }
        return  result;
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSArray*)sortedWidgetList:(NSArray*)widgetList
{
    NSSortDescriptor *firstDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"itemNum" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstDescriptor, nil];

    NSArray *sortedArray = [widgetList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    return sortedArray;
}
```