# sort NSArray using custom objects in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I want to sort my array using custom objects. I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853363/sort-nsarray-with-custom-objects) and of course it works. But the problem is my custom object has an array. I want to sort my data array with this array. If movie has higher alphabetical actors, it should go in front. Example:

```
@interface NSMovie : NSObject
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrActors;
...
@end
```

Now I have list of Movies but i want to sort it based on actors. I know how to sort actors but based on this sorted actors how can I sort my list of movies?

Comment: sort the movies how? If movie has higher alphabetical actors, it should go in front?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @iosDev82 Yeah. Let me edit it.